# "Dug the play" meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ... ... I dug the play.

I accidentally heard a man said the sentence in a TV show. The context is after a play has finished, the man come to an actor and said it.

I can't find any useful information on the web. My best guess is that he *enjoyed the play, or he approved it*.

I might also mishear it!
Thanks!

**Edit**

Is this usage regional? Or it's generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not regional or anything like that. It's slang that's just, maybe, not very common. But I've heard this expression used by American English speakers a couple of times. See the Seinfeld episode [**The Chinese Woman**](http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheChineseWoman.htm) if you really want to hear how it's used. Kramer uses it there:

> You know, I dig Asian women.

**I dig something** just means **I really like it**. So, *I dug the play* simply means *I really liked the play*.

Comment: I would say that the meaning is "I'm into" asian women. Funnily enough, if you dig a hole in the ground, you might end up being... into it.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the context, it may mean you *liked, admired, or appreciated* the play.

[Check MW -](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dig) Used as a *slang,*

> a : to pay attention to, notice - *dig that fancy hat* 
>   b : understand, appreciate - *couldn't dig the medical jargon*
>   c : like, admire - *High school students dig short poetry. —David Burmester*

Answer (score 5):

Let me complete the answer offered by Maulik (and Jason Bassford in the main comments)

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**dig**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dig) [APPROVE]

> [ T ] old-fashioned **slang** to like or understand something
>
> *Hey, I really dig those shoes!*

According to Oxford Dictionary

[**dig**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dig)

> informal with object: Like, appreciate, or understand.
>
> *I really dig heavy rock*

So, the man that you heard liked the play.

Comment: I'm more interested where the usage is applied. Is it regional?

Comment: @dan Well, I'm not native English speaker, I can not answer that. But what do you mean by regional? Used in the US? Used only in some part of the US? Edit your question and include that, probably some US citizen could answer you properly about that subject. I think that it's something general and not regional but I got no proof.

Comment: It used to be very common, in the 60's and 70's, but perhaps only in hippy culture.

Comment: @dan: More generational than regional - "dig it" (along with "groovy" and "foxy" and similar) was popular slang in the '60s and '70s.  Some people (such as myself) still say it occasionally, but it's not that common anymore.

Answer (score 2):

it is not regional it is old fashioned, from the 1950s, from hipsters, "I really dig it man"

http://www.heywoodwakefield.com/dig-slang-1950s/

http://tikiloungetalk.com/2014/02/17/dig-it-man-bop-slangjive-dictionary-from-1955-for-cool-kats-hipsters-gone-man-gone/